# Trouble figuring out how to generate set values only twice for a set amount of times

Tags: android, button, random

I will start off with this is my first post on StackOverflow, so I'm sorry if i leave anything important out, i am also very new at coding and still learning.

What i am trying to is make a form of a memory game, a user will input a number, it will generate that number of tiles (even only) and give them set values. I am stuck on the giving them 2 set values each and only two for x number of tiles.

An example would be if the user choose the lowest number of tiles, 4, there would be two with A and two with B. The code i have right now is a mess but kind of a draft and it is setting text on a button, not a value. This code is also only for the 4 tiles example.

On a side note, I'm sure there is a simpler way to declare all 20 of my buttons, maybe someone could point me in the right direction.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.second_layout);

    Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    Button btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    Button btn3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    Button btn4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn4);
    Button btn5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn5);
    Button btn6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn6);
    Button btn7 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn7);
    Button btn8 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn8);
    Button btn9 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn9);
    Button btn10 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn10);
    Button btn11 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn11);
    Button btn12 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn12);
    Button btn13 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn13);
    Button btn14 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn14);
    Button btn15 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn15);
    Button btn16 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn16);
    Button btn17 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn17);
    Button btn18 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn18);
    Button btn19 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn19);
    Button btn20 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn20);



int tiles = 0;        
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.calling_activity_info_text_view);

    String tileNum = getIntent().getExtras().getString("tilesNumber");

    String[] tileSet = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"};
    Button[] btnA = {btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7, btn8, btn9, btn10, btn11, btn12, btn13
            , btn14, btn15, btn16, btn17, btn18, btn19, btn20};

    if(tileNum.equals("4")) {
        tiles = Integer.parseInt(tileNum);
        tv.setText("" + tiles);
        for(int i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
            btnA[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnA[i].setText(tileSet[i]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about thinking it backwards?

1. Take item from `tileSet`;
2. Set any two buttons with the item you just took;
3. Remove the buttons you set from `btnA` so you don't repeat them;
4. Rinse and repeat until you filled all the buttons defined by `"tileNumber"`.

PS: is there any reason why `"tileNumber"` should be a string? You can add an integer to an intent just as easily.

PS2: You could add the buttons programatically inside a for loop instead of instantiating every single one of them, which would increase scalability.

EDIT:

First of all, to make this work, you'd probably need to replace your button array by an ArrayList so it is easier to remove elements. The code would look something like this:

```
Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < tiles/2; i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
       //Generates random number in the range [0, number of buttons)
        int buttonIndex = random.nextInt(btnA.length());

        // Get button from array
        btnA.get(buttonIndex).setText(tileSet[i]);

        //Remove button from button list
        btnA.remove(buttonIndex);
    }
}
```

Of course this code is not optimized nor saves the reference for the button click, but let me know if it sheds some light into solving the problem.

Comment: As far as tileNumber going, any time i tried to add an integer to an intent it gave me an error. I also tried to pars the string to an int before the intent and that gave me an error.  I already made a loop for my buttons and removed the if statments i had. As far as your idea, that could work but i am a bit confused as to how to do that.

Comment: Could you paste the code where you set the intent? There's a method for every primitive, so you should be able to set an integer without problems.

Comment: Thank you for the response, sorry i did not get back to your earlier with the code. I found a way to do it and it is working just fine right now. I am working on the finishing touches to the app right now. Thanks for trying to help in my time of frustration.

Comment: No worries. But if you found a good solution, consider pasting at least part of it to help others that come across this question and marking it as the accepted answer :)